# Printing values using loop

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops

How can print following values using loop.
Basically i am taking size of array and adding first entry to middle of array if array is of size odd. If it is of even then taking first entry to below to half of array.Just like below i add `1` to `5th` location.

Then second entry to first location. Third entry to below of first entry. Fourth entry to below to second entry. Fifth entry to below to Third entry and up to so on.

In simple First entry to center, second entry to top, third entry to below of center and up to so on.

`2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7`

Comment: What language are you using? Have you wrote some snippet you can share?

Comment: @hypnos I am writing algorithm, language does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convention of pseudocode varies from author to author. This cannot be done in-place. Therefore, you need another array to copy the results.

```
left = 0, right = res.length/2
for i = 0 to res.length - 1:
    if i is even:
        res[right] = arr[i]
        right++
    else
        res[left] = arr[i]
        left++
```

**arr** is your original array and **res** is the empty array you are populating.

Comment: suppose `res.length=8` then `right=7` under loop `i=0` which means `i is even` then it sets `res[7]=arr[0]` that is `res[7]=1`. Which is wrong first element of `arr` is set at `5th` location

Comment: I must be drunk. `right = arr.length/2`. I have the java code right. It's a typo in the pseudocode

Comment: I fixed it. See the edit. Turn that code into java or something and test it :)